# Super-imposing Scenes with QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm still something of a PyQt newbee - I've got a QGraphicsView that displays 3 different QGraphicScenes - they are switched using a dictionary.

```
class MyScenes:

    def _initScenes(self):          
        self._viewer=QGraphicsView()
        self._sinScene=QGraphicScene()
        self._cosScene=QGraphicScene()
        self._tanScene=GraphicScene()
        self._scenes={'sin':self._sinScene,'cos':self._cosScene,'tan':self._tanScene}

    def _showScene(self,ID):            
        self._viewer.setScene(self.scenes[ID])
```

**I want to implement an option that will show the 3 scenes superimposed on one another - not one at a time - how do I do this? Do I need 3 views? Can the view display multiple transparent scenes? Looked around a bit, couldn't find the answer.**

You can answer with Python or C++ - as long as it works in PyQt4.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Since the scene are handled as a hierarchical tree, you could create 3 `QGraphicsItems` inside a single `QGraphicsScene` instead of 3 `QGraphicsScenes`. 

And then you would add the items that are currently in your sin/cos/tan "graphs"/"sub-scenes" as child items of one of those 3 top level items.

Comment: Will take a lot of re-engineering - I'm using QGraphicScene.addLine() to draw with - seems I would have to reimplement everything at a lower level to use QGraphicsItem - but maybe that's my mistake and I did it wrong the first time, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: @Mikey: If you write a `addLine` method in the `QGraphicsItem` derived class that represents your top-level items, you wouldn't need to change anything at the lower level.

Comment: I gather you mean just wrap it and pass it thru to the scene object - will try that - as I said, still new with PyQt, haven't used the more abstract classes yet.

Comment: I tried setting up 3 views for the 3 scenes but they cover each other up - but I think setting up a paintEvent to render transparent would also work.